# How do I rotate 3 groups of 4 people into teams of 3 so that each person in one group works with each person in the other groups?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I have three teams of four people. I would like to create rotating groups of three, where each group has one person from each team, and those people rotate on a staggered schedule so that each person is in the group for 3 slots. 
For example, if team 1 is people a, b, c, and d; team 2 is people e, f, g, and h; team 3 is people i, j, k, l, the start of the schedule might look like this

1. a, e, i
2. b, e, i
3. b, f, i
4. b, f, j
5. c, f, j
6. c, g, j
7. c, g, k
8. d, g, k
9. d, h, k
10. d, h, l
11. a, h, l
12. a, i, l

How do I shift the order in future to make sure that the groups change and everyone gets to work with all of the people on the other teams?

Thanks!

Comment: So I see that $b$ gets to 'work' in shift 2, 3, and 4, while most others do nothing during those shifts?  So is 1 shift simply 1 group of 3 people? And are you looking for a *minimum* number of shifts to accomplish this?  Otherwise, can't you just crank out a new group until you're done? It would seem more interesting of a problem if every shift involves 4 groups of 3 people (i.e. all 12 people), and you want to figure out how to rotate things so that everyone has worked with everyone from all pother groups after a minimum number of shifts .. is that what you meant?

Comment: Excellent question! Yes, the goal is for one person in each group to work during each shift. This team of three, in this case, is responsible for planning and facilitating a meeting, and I want one person from each of three departments on the team. Each member should plan three meetings and then get a break. This will ultimately be a rotating schedule, but I want to ensure that people get to work in all varying combinations with people from different departments.

Comment: Ah, I get it now, thanks!  OK! Then don't pay attention to my earlier posted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that during every shift all 12 people are involved in 4 groups of 3, it obviously takes at least 4 shifts before everyone will have worked at some point with every from all the other groups, because for everyone there are 8 such 'other' people, and during any shift they can only get to meet 2 people.

In fact, here is a schedule that does it in exactly 4 shifts:

\begin{array}{c|cccccccccccc}
Shift&a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h&i&j&k&l\\
\hline
1&1&2&3&4&1&2&3&4&1&2&3&4\\
2&1&2&3&4&2&1&4&3&3&4&1&2\\
3&1&2&3&4&3&4&1&2&4&3&2&1\\
4&1&2&3&4&4&3&2&1&2&1&4&3\\
\end{array}

(so, during every shift, group together the people with the same number)

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a&b&c&d& &e&f&g&h&& i&j&k&l\\ \hline
\color{red}{1}&0&0&0& &\color{red}{1}&0&0&0& &\color{red}{1}&0&0&0 \\ \hline
0&\color{red}{1}&0&0& &0&\color{red}{1}&0&0& &0&\color{red}{1}&0&0 \\ \hline
0&0&\color{red}{1}&0& &0&0&\color{red}{1}&0& &0&0&\color{red}{1}&0 \\ \hline
0&0&0&\color{red}{1}& &0&0&0&\color{red}{1}& &0&0&0&\color{red}{1} \\ \hline
\color{blue}{1}&0&0&0& &0&\color{blue}{1}&0&0& &0&0&\color{blue}{1}&0 \\ \hline
0&\color{blue}{1}&0&0& &0&0&\color{blue}{1}&0& &0&0&0&\color{blue}{1} \\ \hline
0&0&\color{blue}{1}&0& &0&0&0&\color{blue}{1}& &\color{blue}{1}&0&0&0 \\ \hline
0&0&0&\color{blue}{1}& &\color{blue}{1}&0&0&0& &0&\color{blue}{1}&0&0 \\ \hline
\color{red}{1}&0&0&0& &0&0&\color{red}{1}&0& &0&\color{red}{1}&0&0 \\ \hline
0&\color{red}{1}&0&0& &0&0&0&\color{red}{1}& &\color{red}{1}&0&0&0 \\ \hline
0&0&\color{red}{1}&0& &\color{red}{1}&0&0&0& &0&0&0&\color{red}{1} \\ \hline
0&0&0&\color{red}{1}& &0&\color{red}{1}&0&0& &0&0&\color{red}{1}&0 \\ \hline
\color{blue}{1}&0&0&0& &0&0&0&\color{blue}{1}& &0&0&0&\color{blue}{1} \\ \hline
0&\color{blue}{1}&0&0& &\color{blue}{1}&0&0&0& &0&0&\color{blue}{1}&0 \\ \hline
0&0&\color{blue}{1}&0& &0&\color{blue}{1}&0&0& &0&\color{blue}{1}&0&0 \\ \hline
0&0&0&\color{blue}{1}& &0&0&\color{blue}{1}&0& &\color{blue}{1}&0&0&0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray*}